# How do I generate a separate package.json file in the dist directory?

Tags: javascript, gulp, node-modules

I'm creating a package to publish to npm.

1. Can someone please help how do I generate separate package.json and
   place it to dist directory? I'm using gulp as build tool.
2. What should be the contents of the package.json that is meant to be published? I believe we need to exclude devdependencies. I'm not sure about others.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a single package.json for your project, and it's meant to be published on NPM. The idea with `devDependencies` is that they won't get installed when people install your package from NPM, as opposed to `dependencies`, which *do* get installed.

For your package to work as expected, you need at least the `main` field that points to your main JS file.

See [the docs for `package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) for a list of available fields.

Comment: Do you mean I should copy the same package.json file from package directory to dist folder? I've another issue and the issue is that when I install the published package, I don't see `node_modules` folder inside the installed package although there is `devDependencies` in package.json? What could be the mistake? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `package.json` in your directory.

Publish file you want with `files` of `package.json`,

choose your main file (file will call by `require`) with `main` of `package.json`

You should read [npm package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)

Example: (`dist` is directory build by `gulp`)

```
{
    "name": "<your_module>",
    "files": [
        "dist",
        "someFile.js"
    ],
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    ...
}
```

With this way, you should add module build `your module` to `devDependencies`, module was called by `your module` in `dependencies`